# Nuclear spaces and intuition behind their topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, nuclear-spaces

In functional analysis the [**nuclear spaces**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space) (coined by Grothendieck before he became involved in revolutionizing algebraic geometry) can be considered
as a kind of generalization of finite dimensional Euclidean spaces.
While the Banach spaces represent another generalization of
finite-dimensional vector spaces focused on retaining the
properties of norm (and completeness with respect to it) but
losing compactness properties, the focus of the nuclear spaces
lies on retaining compactness properties.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space#Definition) is remarked that informally one can think about
the nuclear spaces to be characterized by the property that their
topology is defined by a family of seminorms whose unit balls
"decrease rapidly in size".

In more detail this means that whenever we are given the unit
ball $B_{1,p}(0) \subset X$ with respect some seminorm
$p: X \to \mathbb{R}$, we can find a "much smaller" unit
ball $B_{1,q}(0) \subset X$ with respect another seminorm
$q: X \to \mathbb{R}$ inside it, or that any neighborhood
of $0$ contains a "much smaller" neighborhood.

What does it mean precisely that the unit ball $B_{1,q}(0)$
is "much smaller" than the unit ball $B_{1,p}(0)$? "Much smaller"
in what sense? Can it be made precise what this means here? (the question is really about the intuition)

Comment: Your question is already answered by the Wikipedia article that you referenced: Property 7 in the “Characterizations” section make this precise: for any seminorm p p we can find a larger seminorm q q so that the natural map X_q→X_p is nuclear.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: yes the nuclear maps essentially mimic (in certain sense) the structure of linear map between finite dimensional vspaces $X \to Y$ to be given by the sum $\sum a_i x_i' \otimes y_i$ where for certain $x_i' \in X'$ and $y_i \in Y$ and scalars $a_i$. For sure in infinite dimensions not all maps are of this type. But I not see what does it in this sense mean that the unit ball $B_{1,q}(0) \subset X$ is "musch smaller" than unit ball $B_{1,p}(0) \subset X$. What here the formulation "much smaller" mean?

Comment: This is answered in my comment above.   Property 7 is a precise formulation of “much smaller”.  Nuclear maps are maps with “small” image, intuitively.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: If I try to express it in layman's words than the intuition behind $X_q \to X_p$ beeing nuclear seems to be that "typical open sets" like balls with respect to seminorm $q$ look "skinny" trough glasses of the topology induced by seminorm $p$. So in some way the nuclear maps "narrow" the volume of the images of open sets in domain (**not** in the sense of a "scalling" but more in degrees of freedom sense; I don't know how to express it better; ) making looking them "sparse" comparing with typical open sets of the codomain space. Is this intuition of nuclear maps halfway correct?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the Wikipedia article is alluding to above: the unit ball of X_q becomes “much smaller” when mapped to X_p, i.e., the unit ball of q is “much smaller” than the unit ball of p.

Comment: The basic intuition is that for a nuclear operator.  I think that a good way to think of this is via the analogy in the commutative cases-- bounded operators  like $~\ell^\infty$, compact operators $~c_0$, nuclear operators $~\ell^1$ (and on Hilbert space, Hilbert-Schmidt operators $~\ell^2$).  This is even exact for sequences acting as diagonal operators on $\ell^2$.

Comment: Have a look  Gelfand and Vilenkin "Generalized functions. Applications of harmonic analysis*. This is the 4th volume of the 5 volume   gem about generalized functions by   Gelfand and various coauthors.  Section  I.3 of volume  4 discusses a  special, but very general class of nuclear spaces. These  examples will cover most concrete needs,  and it has the advantage  that the arguments are much more transparent than in the general case.

Answer (score 4):

Some night thoughts on this question.  At the level of operators,  bounded operators are analogous to bounded sequences, compact to $c_0$ ones and nuclear to $\ell^1$.  This analogy is precise in the sense that if we regard a sequence as a multiplication operator $T$  on $\ell^2$ in the usual way, then  the bounded ones correspond exactly to $\ell^\infty$ and so on.

For nuclear spaces, we remain for the moment in the context of sequence spaces.  Suppose that we have an unbounded sequence $(\lambda_n)$ with terms $\geq 1$.  Then we can create, in a simple and natural way, a sequence $H^n$ ($n$ a whole number) of Hilbert spaces, where $H^n$ is the domain of definition of $T^n$ for $n$ positive, and $H^{-n}$  is its dual (under the scalar product of $\ell^2$).  Then we can close the sequence with the intersection $\bigcap H^n$  and the union $\bigcup H^{-n}$  and these are an $F$-space and a $DF$-space respectively.  (The Hilbert spaces can easily be identified with weighted $\ell^2$´s).

The connection with nuclearity lies in the fact that the limit spaces are nuclear when $\left(\frac 1{\lambda_n}\right) $ is in $\ell^1$.

The connection with the real world (i.e., the classical nuclear spaces of test functions and distributions)  arises from the fact that we can, using the spectral theorem, carry out the same construction with an unbounded self-adjoint operator  $T$ on Hilbert space.  The resulting limit spaces are again nuclear, if $T$ has a discrete spectrum with eigenvalues $(\lambda_n)$ which satisfy the above condition.  (In fact it suffices that there exist a positive $\alpha$ so that $\left(\frac 1{\lambda_n^\alpha}\right)$ in $\ell^1$).

If one applies this construction to classical operators (Sturm-Liouville, Laplace, Schrödinger) whose spectral properties are known, then one obtains a unified approach to many of the classical spaces of distribution theory.